# How to Set View Filter Operator to "Less Than Or Equal To" <= in Views Filter Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I want to Set View Filter Operator to 
"Less Than Or Equal To" **<=** in Views Filter of Drupal 7.

**MACHINE NAME** field_guests
**FIELD TYPE** List (integer)
**WIDGET** Select list

[image]

Comment: Please migrate to drupal.stackexchange.com for better responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

filtering on less than or equal to on a integer list is not possible, since this list is not necessarily a logical sequence of numbers. Change your field type to integer instead, and if necessary define maximum and minimum values for it. This should enable you to make the option less than or equal to available in your exposed filters.

Comment: Ok this work. Thanks a lot. Now I have a little problem in Views filter. How to change the textbox to list with numbers from minimum to maximum?

Comment: Glad I could help. Not sure what you're trying to do. Like I said, you can define absolute minimum and maximum values for field_guests, which means that the system won't accept values above or below. This can be set in admin/structure/types/manage/YOURCONTENTTYPE/fields/field_guests. If you want others to use the view filter, they cannot get a list since the values of the field are merely in a range between a min and max. You can add a description to the filter if you think this may be confusing to your visitors, so they know these min and max values exist.